# Dismiss modal segue embedded inside UINavigationController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

My viewController hierarchy (UPDATED):

- `mainViewController`, embed segue to:

  - `containerViewController`, custom (empty) segue to:

    - `navigationController` embed segue to:

      - `viewController1`, push segue to:

        - `viewController2`, modal segue to:

          - `modalViewController`

In modalViewController I have a done-button that triggers

`[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

In theory, that line will dismiss the modal segue and go back to the parent viewController, in this case viewController2.

Instead I go back to navigationController.rootViewController, in this case viewController1, and the navigationBar inside it gets this flickering animation.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just tried the same configuration on a new project and works as expected (dismisses the modal and stays at the 2nd controller)... Also, your close action can be simplified to `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` (which automatically forwards the message to the presenting controller)

Comment: In the post, I simplified the viewController hierarchy and hoped someone could confirm that the dismissal should work. Thanks for your reply! I've updated the viewController hierarchy to better reflect my storyboard. `self.presentingViewController` is just for better clarity of what's actually going on here.